# Linux selective USB-Locking against evil-maid-attacks

Tags: linux, usb, physical-access, badusb

While the question of completely disabling usb-controllers and -storage to defeat an evil-maid-attack has already been answered here quite often, I have a different solution in mind.

Upon locking the GUI, the system would

- iterate over the already connected usb devices,
- lock all other ports, and
- while being locked check the connected devices

If a device is removed from the system, a specific action is taken like locking all usb-ports or powering down the system. This would obviously not prevent a skilled attack, but would prevent the literal evil-maid (technically unversatile person with physical access, which has been instructed to "just plug this thing between keyboard and computer").

Anyone knows if a script doing that already exists?

*Sidenote: Yes I know of Law 3, that this does not provide complete security, yadayada. Still, a good line of defense means to have several moving parts and having this script **would** increase the physical security in environments, where you are unable to do more (yes those exist).*